# Convert JSON to Java object second parameter null using Gson library

Tags: java, json, gson

I´m having a trouble converting a JSON to a Java Object using Gson library.

here is my Dispositivo.java class

```
public class Dispositivo {

private String codigo;
private String nombreusuario;

public Dispositivo(){}

public Dispositivo(String codigo, String nombreusuario) {
    super();
    this.setCodigo(codigo);
    this.setNombreusuario(nombreusuario);
}

public String getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getNombreusuario() {
    return nombreusuario;
}

public void setNombreusuario(String nombreusuario) {
    this.nombreusuario = nombreusuario;
}  public Dispositivo transformJSONStringToDispositivoObject(String dispositivoJSON) {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Dispositivo dispositivo = gson.fromJson(dispositivoJSON, Dispositivo.class);

    System.out.println("Dispositivo convertido de JSON a Objeto: "+dispositivo.getCodigo()+":"+dispositivo.getNombreusuario()+":");
    return dispositivo;
}
}
```

Using the method
 `Dispostivo d = new Dispositivo(transformJSONStringToDispositivoObject("{"codigo":"5555555","nombreususario":"usuarioDePrueba"}"));`

It returns a Dispositivo("5555555",null);

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in field name:

```
Dispostivo d = new Dispositivo(transformJSONStringToDispositivoObject("
{"codigo":"5555555","nombreususario":"usuarioDePrueba"}"));
```

`nombreususario` is not the field name in your class, it's `nombreusuario`. Change the JSON string or the name of your class field and then it will work.